# realloc()/HeapRealloc() fails even though enough memory is available

Tags: c++, winapi, dynamic-memory-allocation

My machine has 8GB of RAM and is running Windows Server 2008. `malloc()`/`realloc()` fails to allocate more memory when my application has 1.5~1.7GB already allocated. I tried switching to `HeapAlloc()`/`HeapRealloc()` instead and the same situation happens.

Is there something I am missing here? What could be causing my application to be unable to allocate more memory when there is clearly available RAM?

Comment: How much memory are you trying to acquire? Is your application a 32-bit or 64-bit one?

Comment: Windows is 64Bit and my application is 32Bit. It is unlikely to be a fragmentation issue, since last time I debugged it, it failed when trying to reallocate ~7MB chunk into ~9MB chunk, and free memory is around 5GB.

Comment: By free meory you mean RAM? Instead of seeing the free RAM available you need to see the largest contiguos free space available in your virtual address space. If it is less than the memory you are asking for, allocation will fail. This is caused mostly because of heap fragmentation.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not get you. How come 5GB free RAM not contain a contiguous 9MB space?

Comment: You need to understand the difference between a virtual memory and physical memory first. Take a look at this link:http://www.aumha.org/win5/a/xpvm.php

Comment: Very informative link, thanks a lot. Any suggestions on how I can get around this? I am thinking of moving more of "inactive" allocated data to hard disk files instead of dynamic allocations.

Comment: Did you try LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag? It allows 32 bit app to use more memory on Windows 64 bit.

Comment: I am going for LARGEADDRESSAWARE now, unfortunately a huge amount of data processing is involved, I would not know whether it worked or not for at least another 15 hours or so.

Comment: You need to decide whether you *really* require that much amount of data to be present in your process address space at a given point of time. If you require only a portion of the data then you can use something like a memory mapped files to solve the issue. If you require that much of data to be present, I suggest you to port your application to 64 bit. You can move the inactive data to the hard disk using memory mapped files with the page file as the backing store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What could be causing my application to be unable to allocate more memory when there is clearly available RAM?

***Heap fragmentation***. Allocation doesn't simply ask for memory. It asks for a contiguous piece of memory.

Of course, given the sparse data you provided (***how much*** are you trying to re-alloc when that happens? is this a ***32bit or a 64bit*** app?), there could be other problems as well.

Answer (score 4):

It just doesn't matter how much RAM you are having in your machine. Each 32 bit process on Windows gets a 4GB address space out of which 2GB is available in user-address space. So the memory for your program (including its code, dlls loaded, stack etc)  will be allocated from this space only. Since you are nearing the limits of the virtual address space the memory allocating is failing.

Answer (score 2):

By default on Windows 32-bit OS you can use 2DB for one process. If you use MSVC compiler you have to set [LARGEADDRESSAWARE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz223b1z(v=VS.100).aspx) option.

Comment: Um, is Windows Server 2008 _32bit_??

Comment: LargeAddressAware flag is necessary for 64 bit application also as I know.

Comment: Not only does your OS need to be 64 bit (which is the case here) you also need to compile your application to be 64 bit. Note that LARGEADDRESSAWARE option only enables use of the full 32 bit for your virtual addresses, above that you need a 64 bit compile.

Comment: @Sean: TTBOMK it only enables you to use 3GB of the 4GB address space. 1GB is always reserved for the OS.

Comment: @sbi: It enables use 3 Gb on windows server 32 bit (with /3G flag), but on Windows 64bit it's possible to use up to 4 Gb.

Comment: I don't know the details for LARGEADDRESSAWARE and 32 bit systems but the doc say "larger then 2G"... A little bit must be reserved for kernel space calls to go to...

Comment: @DReJ: I see. In a test project, I just had an application allocate (and write to) almost 15GB of memory on my 4GB Win7 64bit notebook, before the system was crawling so slowly that ressetting and restarting the machine was faster than closing the application. That wasn't contiguous memory, though, the biggest contiguous block the program was able to allocate was 4GB.