# "MemoryError" in VSCode but not in Jupyter/AnacondaPrompt

Tags: python, memory, visual-studio-code

I am running into a MemoryError at around 2 GB on my Python implementation of a split_train_test function on the MNIST data set.

Task Manager barely reaches 50% of max memory, including the other apps that are open on my machine. I have 16GB of RAM.

I see most people point towards a [64 vs 32 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554876/memory-error-in-visual-studio-but-plenty-of-memory-available) or python 2 vs 3 problem; however, both my VS Code and Windows 10 are 64-bit and view > Command Palette > Python: Select Interpreter show that I am using Python 3.7.1 64-bit from anaconda3/conda.

I know the code itself works because I have used the output in Jupyter afterI import the py file.

```py
    def split_train_val(val_frac=0.3, size=1):
        """Splits training and validation set

        param val_frac: fraction of total training set to be used for validation
        """
        # Read converted csv
        X_raw = pd.read_csv('Data/csv/X_train.csv')
        Y_raw = pd.read_csv('Data/csv/y_train.csv')

        # Rename Label column, concat to X set
        Y_raw.columns = ['Label']
        df = pd.concat([Y_raw, X_raw], axis=1).sample(frac=size)

        # Split training set into train and val
        N = df.shape[0] 
        n = round(val_frac * N)
        train = df.iloc[n:,:]
        val = df.iloc[:n,:]

        x_train = train.drop(['Label'], axis=1)
        x_val = val.drop(['Label'], axis=1)
        y_train = train.Label
        y_val = val.Label


        # Return training and validation set
        return(x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val)


    x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = split_train_val()
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "preprocessing.py", line 71, in <module>
    x_train, y_train, x_val, y_val = split_train_val()
  File "preprocessing.py", line 53, in split_train_val
    df = pd.concat([Y_raw, X_raw], axis=1).sample(frac=size)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 229, in concat
    return op.get_result()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 426, in get_result
    copy=self.copy)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 2052, in concatenate_block_managers
    values = values.copy()
MemoryError
```

Lastly, I tried changing the jedi.memoryLimit setting to -1 as suggested by some VS Code documentation. This did not help either.

I imported then ran the function in Jupyter. I have also run this exact code in my Anaconda Prompt. None of them result in any error.

Answer (score 1):

VS Code and Windows 10 may be 64-bit for you, but your installation of Python is 32-bit as shown by your path: `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\`. Try explicitly installing a 64-bit version of Python and make sure to select it in VS Code.